# Getting ArgumentException: Invalid type parameter using ActionResult<JsonResult>> as a return type after upgrading to .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, json, api, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

I'm getting the following runtime error when trying to hit any of my API endpoints that are built like the code seen below:

```
ArgumentException: Invalid type parameter 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult' specified for 'ActionResult<T>'.
```

[image: error]

This code functioned as expected in my app in .NET Core 2.1. After upgrading to .NET Core 2.2, this broke.

Here's the code for one of me endpoints in a controller.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<JsonResult>> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            MongoConnector mongo = new 
            MongoConnector(_configService.GetMongoConnectionString());

            List<BsonDocument> queues = await mongo.AggregateQueues(
                (aggregator) => aggregator
                                .Match(CommonAggregation.SinceYesterday)
                                .Sort(CommonAggregation.SortByDate)
                                .Group(QueueAggregators.GroupQueuesByMessagingName)
            );


            List<QueueHealth> queueHealth = await MongoConnector.DeserializeList<QueueHealth>(queues);
            JsonResult result = new JsonResult(queueHealth);
            result.Value = queueHealth;
            result.ContentType = "application/json";
            result.StatusCode = 200;

            return result;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex, "An exception was thrown within /api/MessageQueue");

            return new StatusCodeResult(InternalServerError);
        }
    }
```

Anyone have any insight on what changed between 2.1 and 2.2 that would cause this? I can't even find anyone else mentioning a similar issue or documentation on the change online.

Comment: Have you tried changing `Task<ActionResult<JsonResult>>` to `Task<JsonResult>`

Comment: @Kahbazi Yes, the issue with that is that I sometimes need to return a `StatusCodeResult` instead. I can work around by just returning `Task<ActionResult>`, but this is a breaking change for my frontend consumers.

Comment: yes returning `Task<ActionResult>` is the right thing to do. I don't see how changing thi would break the client

Comment: @Kahbazi I can again work around it, but if the only change is the return type then I'm losing a layer of Json, which the frontend isn't expecting. Mostly I'm just confused as to why this working code in 2.1 doesn't work in 2.2. Appreciate the help though!

Comment: you are still returning `JsonResult`. Your frontend still gets json

Comment: @Kahbazi Right, but without modification the json will be structured differently. I get data, but lose my ContentType and StatusCode, and my frontend is expecting to dig a layer deeper in the json to get the data.

Comment: You may just need to rethrow the exception instead of returning the status code yourself

Answer (score 5):

`JsonResult` already implements `IActionResult` and inherits from `ActionResult` as you can see in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2). So you should return `Task<IActionResult>` in case you want to return other types of results too.

However, I suggest you consider to not try and catch general exceptions as these will anyways be handled by the system and a status code of 500 will be returned.

Comment: This answer helped me, thank you. I am also catching general exceptions in order to log them as we communicate with a third party component. Do you have any alternative to suggest?

Comment: @AlejandroB. logging responses that have a status 500 (and much more) is responsibility of the infrastructure where your app is running on. For example, we use AppInsights and Azure even sends us an e-mail if there's a 500 occurring. This should all be configurable outside your app.